# Graphql - File Upload from Java Client to Node.js Server

Tags: java, graphql, multipartform-data

I need to upload a File / Files from a Java "Client" (which is actually a background proccess) to a node.js Server via GraphQL....

Im fully aware that there are (way) better ways of doing this, but that's (unfortunately) the setup I'm stuck with.

Been working on this for a couple days now - without any success...

What I know is, that I need to send a multipart request to my graphql mutation endpoint. But I'm either to bad at Java, to new to GraphQL and/or simply to stupid to do this...

What I gathered from the little ressources that are out there:

*Server Side*

On the Server Side im working with the Appollo-Express Server

From what I read in the official [Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/guides/file-uploads.html), I need a Schema which's looking like the following:

```
[...]
type Query{
   uploads:[File]
}

type Mutation {
    singleUpload(file: Upload!): File!
}
type File {
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    encoding: String!
} 
[...]
```

With a resolver looking somewhat like:

```
    [...]
    Mutation: {
        async singleUpload(parent, { file }) {
            const { stream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await file;

            *DO MAGIC*
        }
    }
    [...]
```

*Client Side*

TBH, im at a loss... I tried multiple ways of creating a Multipart Form, appending the File, Filename and what not... Tried multiple ways of builing the Query, with or without a "variable" Tag, etc. etc. but I got the feeling, that I'm not even close to getting it right.

I know how to send Form Data via REST (well... with extensive use of google), but can't wrap my head around doing the same with a graphql call.

Does anyone have any clue on how this is doable? Or at least some hints as what I could do? Google aint helping me at all with this.

Cheers